# Riemann sums with natural log

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, riemann-sum

Let $f(x)=\ln(x)$ on $[1,2]$. Let the partitions be given as $P_n=(a=1,\frac{n+1}{n},\frac{n+2}{n},...,\frac{2n-1}{n},2=b)$ for $n\in \mathbb{Z} \geq1$

**1)** I want to calculate the upper and lower sums. I have $\Delta x=\frac1n$ and I'm using this formula (let me know if it's wrong):

**Upper sum $U(f,P_n)$:**
$$f(c_i)=\ln(1+\frac{i}{n})$$
Taking the sum
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\ln(1+\frac{i}{n})$$

**Lower sum $L(f,P_n)$**
$$f(c_i)=\ln(1+\frac {i-1}{n})$$
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\ln(1+\frac{i-1}{n})$$
I have tried calculating this for like two days. I keep getting the wrong result. (BTW I have been trying to confirm it by inserting for n=3 and comparing it with a Riemann sum calculator).

My problem is when I take the sum, I know that the $i$ becomes $n!$ but how can I calculate when I have different terms ($1+\frac{i-1}{n}$) in $\ln$? I could maybe write it as

$$\frac{1}{n}[\sum_{i=1}^n\ln(n+i-1)-\sum_{i=1}^n\ln(n+i)]$$
?

**2)** Show that $$U(f,P_n)-L(f,P_n)=\frac{\ln(2)}{n}$$

Since $f$ is monotone I could use $$\Delta x \times[f(b)-f(a)]=\frac1 n[\ln 2 - \ln 1]=\frac{\ln(2)}{n}$$ Does that make sense? I haven't really used the upper and lower sums, so it seems "too easy".

Comment: Ultimately to show that $U-L$ can be written as $\ln(2)/n$. But I didn't want to ask so directly. I am having trouble with the formula for the sums. I can't seem to make it work. Is the one I have written correct? (the one with $f(c_i)$

Comment: I am aware that when you increase the number of partitions $P$ U and L will converge to each other.Yes this is part of a longer mandatory assignment. We are supposed to prove what I stated above. (I know it doesn't seem clear what I'm asking, since I'm only stating part of the question).

Comment: n partitions. I want to 1) calculate upper and lowe sums. 2) Show that U-L = ln(2)/n

Comment: You wrote "I could maybe write it as $$\frac{1}{n}[\sum_{i=1}^n\ln(n+i-1)-\sum_{i=1}^n\ln(n+i)]"$$ This equals $$L(f,P_n)-U(f,P_n)$$ If you let $n=3$, then $$U(f,P_n)=\frac{1}{3}\left(\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{3}\right)+\ln\left(1+\frac{2}{3}\right)+\ln 2\right)=$$

$$=\frac{1}{3}\ln\left(\frac{4}{3}\cdot \frac{5}{3}\cdot 2\right)=$$

$$=\frac{1}{3}\ln\left(\frac{40}{9}\right)$$